# Dynamically add h1 in header

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

How do i dynamically add a value for `h1` in my header in jQuery Mobile to make it from

```
<div data-role="header"> 
<h1></h1> 
</div>
```

to this

```
<div data-role="header"> 
<h1>Page Title</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: same effect `$(".ui-header .ui-title").text("new title");`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$("div[data-role='header']").find('h1').html('Page Title')
```

With id:

```
$("div[data-role='header']").find('#h1ID').html('Page Title')
```

Comment: Is there a similar soln if my h1 had a id ?

Comment: please see.updated now

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[data-role*=header] > h1').html('some content')
```